# How to make single AsyncTask for different service or different urls

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, background

Is there any way to create a single `AsyncTask` in android for different background services or different urls.
If yes, how can we create a comman `doInBackground()` method for different different background services

Comment: Yes Sure you can do it... Pass the urls and get response in doinbackground.....

Answer (score 0):

For more than one url you can pass an Array of urls to your AsyncTask class and do the task for each url.

But if you want to run more than one background task (specific task defined in your AsyncTask) in different time, then you have to create several object each time you want to execute the task.

Please remind you can't call execute method twice for a particular object if the task is already running.

Thanks